# In C++/WinRT, is it possible to defer activation of a composed base class?

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, midl

Let's say you declare a runtime class that derives from (i.e., composes) a runtime base class.

From what I can tell, C++/WinRT will set up your class so that the base class is activated automatically during construction.  I think it takes place within the constructor of a (compile-time) base class.

But is it possible to somehow override that behavior so that you activate the base class when and how you so choose? For example, perhaps at runtime, you'd like to choose between some different intermediate classes to serve as the composed object.

I think ATL gives you this ability, since you're in control and responsible for instantiating an aggregated component.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure what your question is about. WinRT are a set of language-agnostic interfaces and coclasses that are declared to implement them. There's a big gap between these contracts (an interface is a binary contract) and the concrete class(es) which implements them, as implementation is always a private matter, only the contracts being public. You can have IMy and IMy2 implemented by two different concrete classes for example. And then, there is C++/WinRT which is a set of tool and code to "bind" the C++ language to these WinRT classes in a C++-oriented manner.

Comment: Can you sketch out some code that describes what you're trying to achieve, ideally a [mcve] (including the .idl)?